# Is battery level info available while using iOS Simulator? Even sample app crashes

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator

I have installed [Battery 1.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/battery) from pub but can't get it to work in iOS Simulator.
I tried the example app included in the pub, and also my own simple implementation. Both work fine in Android emulator, but in iOS simulator they throw the following

```
Exception has occurred.  PlatformException (PlatformException(UNAVAILABLE, Battery info unavailable, null))
```

I've googled, but can't confirm if this info is available at all in iOS simulator, so I don't know if this is a problem on my side.

Is it possible to check for battery level in the simulator at all?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with IOS simulator. Then I've tried on real IOS device and works well.

Comment: thank you for confirming this. 1.5 years later I still never found an official note mentioning this limitation.